# rsProcessingAborted & rsErrorOpeningConnection

Tags: reporting-services

After I deploy my SSRS report to Windows Server 2008 R2 and I click on the reporting that I uploaded to the server, can't show the report that I want, it caused the following error:

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
>   Cannot create a connection to data source 'MYDCBDataSource'.
>   (rsErrorOpeningConnection) For more information about this error
>   navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable
>   remote error

s

May I know how to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: @R.Richards the solution still can't solve the current problem

Comment: Have you set up a datasource called MYDCBDataSource for the report?

Comment: @Snowlockk it mean that I have to upload MYDCBDataSource in to the server also?

Comment: @Snowlockk yes, already set the MYDCBDataSource in the reserver